Затрекать трафик с мобильной версии сайта в GA
Нужны ли какие-то дополнительные настройки в GA для эвентов, чтобы трекать трафик с мобильной версии сайта?
В данный момент эвенты отрабатываются на десктопной версии, но в Preview mode видно, что с мобильной версии сайта ни один эвент не трекается.
